# Git branching strategy for custom features

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I'd like to get some suggestions towards an optimal Git branching strategy for a project I'm working on.

There's an open source program (I'll call it "PRIMARY") that I want to fork and add several specialized features to (I'll call this modified version "SPECIAL"). These features (I'll call them "FEATURE1" and "FEATURE2" are probably not generally useful enough to warrant them being added to the mainline development of PRIMARY, but I would like to make the changes for FEATURE1 or FEATURE2 available for anyone that wants them. PRIMARY is being actively developed and I want to keep SPECIAL current with these changes along with my features continuing to be added in.

My goals would be to create a public repository that makes it easy to

1. update SPECIAL with the changes for new versions of PRIMARY;
2. create new versions of SPECIAL with FEATURE1 and FEATURE2 added in;
3. isolate the necessary changes to add FEATURE1 or FEATURE2 to any version of PRIMARY.

I've been experimenting with various strategies but don't feel like I've found the optimal solution yet. My original thought was using the master branch for SPECIAL, a vendor branch to track the changes to PRIMARY, branches off of the vendor branch for FEATURE1/FEATURE2, and then merge the feature branches into the master branch to generate the final SPECIAL program. But how to handle updates to PRIMARY? My attempts all required making the same changes (and resolving conflicts) manually to multiple branches whenever PRIMARY was updated. That seems wrong to me and not DRY.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you fork, you will have to maintain the updates from the original project (PRIMARY) by yourself. It wouldn't be a good practice. Imagine the project increases in popularity (if not already) and gets 1000 more developers. You will have to keep up with all of their updates.

The first option would be to fork the project, implement FEATURE1, FEATURE2 and then ask them to merge the changes. Since you have stated: "`... are probably not generally useful enough to warrant them being added to the mainline ...`" this option fails.

That brings me to the second option. If those features are not useful to the mainline, maybe you should not fork in the first place. Maybe you should have a small project of your own that depends on the open source one and only contains the functionality for the 2 features. Think of it as a pulg-in.

But let's say that you want to stick to your scenario. In that case I will definitely have at least 6 branches:

- `master` - release branch of my own
- `vendor` - tracking the updates from the original project
- `development` - tracking the updates of my development and the original project
- `feature1` - as implies
- `feature2` - as implies

The `featureX` branches are self explanatory. In the `vendor` branch all the changes from the original project are going to be merged (hard work). The `development` branch is the branch in which both the `vendor` and the `featuresX` are going to be merged. Once the code is going to be functional, `development` branch should be merged into `master` and there should be a new release.

Also, the `vendor` branch does not have to have all the changes in the original project. You can only update the `vendor` branch only from their release branch.

I think this should be a good documentation for how branching should be done: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thanks, I'd read that but the strategy doesn't fit what I'm trying to do. It assumes that features are gradually merged into the mainline code. In this case, the hard part is that the features will likely never be merged into PRIMARY. In the diagram on that page, the features are gradually merged to the right (from feature branches into develop and then to release). In my case, the feature branches are independent of the vendor branch but need to track with them somehow and it all needs to merge into the release branch.

Comment: @ScottBussinger I updated the answer. You could use another branch (let's say development) to track the changes from the vendor and the ones from your features. Since this is an opinionated question you risk to be downvoted, so I suggest you to be a bit more specific.

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but best I can tell, I have to merge changes (and resolve conflicts) in the vendor branch manually into the development branch, as well as both feature branches separately. I was hoping there was some way to avoid that.